# How to feature select from a feature importance chart?

Tags: r, survival, random-forest, feature-selection

[image]

I made a feature importance chart using the random forest algorithm.

I want to perform feature selection on survival data.

How could I use this graph to feature select?

```
                  event.1   event.2
AMOUNT              0.2455    0.0108
INSTALL_RATE        0.0535    0.0239
FOREIGN             0.0413    0.0640
PROPERTY            0.0390    0.0016
HISTORY             0.0278    0.0279
AGE                 0.0169    0.0323
NUM_CREDITS         0.0168    0.0156
OTHER_INSTALL       0.0136   -0.0174
RESIDENCE           0.0096   -0.0105
GUARANTOR           0.0095    0.0094
JOB                 0.0087    0.0087
CHK_ACCT            0.0079   -0.0035
PRESENT_RESIDENT    0.0070   -0.0086
NUM_DEPENDENTS      0.0062    0.0018
COAPPLICANT         0.0054    0.0072
EMPLOYMENT          0.0037    0.0014
PURPOSE             0.0021    0.0071
TELEPHONE           0.0010    0.0148
SEX                 0.0009    0.0141
SAV_ACCT           -0.0014   -0.0093
```

Comment: Why you want to do feature selection will influence what kind of answer is useful, so why do you want to select features at all?

Comment: @Dave I want to feature select so I can see which features influence quicker or slower time to `DEFAULT`

Answer (score 1):

The feature importance chart already shows "which features influence quicker or slower time to `DEFAULT`," at least insofar as you can tell that with a tree-based model. "Feature selection" usually means finding a subset of features and building a smaller model just using the selected features, but there's seldom a need to do that. If you already have built a reliable survival random forest, you can just use it for predictions without further feature selection.

If you have a question about whether a particular feature leads to greater or lower hazard of default, you could try fixing all the other features at identical levels and then varying the one of particular interest. That can be tricky, however, as the random forest can involve multiple interactions among features, hidden from direct view. In principle those interactions could alter the apparent direction of association of any feature with outcome as the values of the other features change.

Comment: This makes so much sense. Thank You. So it sounds like if a feature wasn't valuable at all, it would not have shown up in the feature importance chart.

I have a question. Does Event 1 refer to the prediction of censored values?

Comment: @Antonio that depends on how you set up the model and data, and the software that you used, which you didn't specify. Check the documentation for the software.